# nodejs convert stream to json object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, stream, tar

I have a tar stream and would like to convert it to JSON, i'm using JSONstream package, it is convenient and easy however while dealing with large data volumes the heap memory seems to be grow continuously and slows down the whole process.

Any simple and memory sensitive way to convert stream to JSON in nodejs, please share your thoughts.

```
let extract = tarStream.extract();
extract.on('entry', (header, stream, next) => {
   stream.on('data', (chunks) {
     console.log(chunks) // <Buffer 22 6c 61 73 74 55 70 64 61 74 65 64.... >
   })
});
```

I need to convert the above to JSON object.